# the (at) sign to look up username in textarea

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know of any js (jquery) library that react to the @ sign when you are writing in a textarea and does a json lookup, similiar to what Facebook does in the status box? I'm not looking for autocomplete for input boxes.

Comment: This *is* just a modification of the same technique used for autocomplete. The difference is in the trigger, not in the server interaction.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider trying to register a keyhandler on your page/input that could listen for an @ sign, then act as more characters are typed in.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#MainContent_TextBox1').keydown(function (event) {
            if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 50)
                //Go find $('#MainContent_TextBox1').val() in the DB
                //Then $('#MainContent_TextBox1').val(search-result);
         });`
```